# Getting a list of compiled dlls/pdbs for use in AfterBuild in MSBuild

Tags: msbuild

The jist is I want to copy all the compiled files from a project to another folder after a build is finished.  I figured I would use a Copy task in the AfterBuild target.  Is there any way to get a list of built files in this target so I know exactly which files to copy?

Thanks

Update:

Read my comment below to see how I figured this out.  However, this isn't an elegant solution.  What I am really looking for is an ItemGroup of built files.  Does that exist?

Comment: Well, after thrashing on this for awhile I found something that worked, but it doesn't seem very clean.  There is an Item Group called FileWrites that lists all the files that were written to.  After I exclude a funky cache file, I get the list I want.  Here is my after build task:
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <ItemGroup>
     <SourceFiles Include="@(FileWrites)" Exclude="**\*.cache" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(SourceFiles)" DestinationFolder="..\..\..\Deploy\IanPmServices\bin" />   
  </Target>

Answer (score 1):

The build process does what it needs to & writes what it needs to.  It doesn't know that you in particular are only interested in a subset of what it does.

Why do you think the FileWrites itemgroup isn't clean enough?

Our build process ouputs .dll & .pdb, and also .config, .xml, .doc.  We use post-build copy operations based on the FileWrites group, including a couple of conditional operations for a few customer-specific files.

Edit:

With our upcoming Silverlight project, we'll also be dealing with .xaml & .xap.

Comment: the FileWrites contains multiple copies of the files, from the output path and the obj dir, as well as a .cache file that I don't need.  It works, but I have to scrub the data a bit to get what I actually want.  Seems that this should just be something available (it is when calling a msbuild task).  I'm just confirming that there isn't anything available that I havent found yet.

Comment: Can you use the output of the individual tasks that do provide the list to do the copy at task-end instead of job-end?  >>...should just be something available...<< the generic build process has no way of knowing what files are significant to a particular task.  For instance, I use an Exec task to run a PowerBuilder application compile.  There's no way for anything to know that the output .exe & .pbd are significant, and the written-at-the-same-time .bak & .pbl are not.  That's up to me to know & to script for.